# java - fast bitmasks larger than 64 bits

Tags: java, arrays, bit-manipulation, java-7, biginteger

What is the most efficient data structure to handle (i.e. perform all bitwise operations on) bitmasks that are of a known size but larger than 64bits?

`byte[]`? `BigInteger`? Something else entirely?

Needs to be Java 7 compatible and should be fast (or at least as fast as can reasonably be expected, given their size) for things like

```
if(bitmask & 7 != 0){...}
```

and

```
bitmask1 |= bitmask2
```

and so on.

Comment: BigInteger can certainly do all of those things.  But, a BigInteger instance is immutable, so any operation on it will produce a new BigInteger object.  You may need to try it to determine whether the performance is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it directly because maximum size for a primitive number which can be used as a bitmask is actually 64 bit for a long value. What you can do is to split the bitmask into 2 or more ints or longs and then manage it by hand.

```
int[] mask = new int[4];
final int MAX_SHIFT = 32;

void set(int b) {
  mask[b / MAX_SHIFT] |= 1 << (b % MAX_SHIFT);
}

boolean isSet(int b) {
  return (mask[b / MAX_SHIFT] & (1 << (b % MAX_SHIFT))) != 0;
}
```

Or you use a BitSet

```
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(101);
bitSet.set(100);
```

Comment: Yeah, BitSet is fast enough, and has some nice operations. Though not _shifting_ bits.

Comment: @JoopEggen for the right-shift, at least, there's a solution to that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008150/shifting-a-java-bitset (they call it left shift, but a left shift goes the other direction, for me). For left shifts, I don't immediately see a solution but to extend ``BitSet`` and add a method that would increment the stored values by a given amount. Do you?

Comment: @User1291 seems a subrange of the original bitset but not reindexed. A part of the shifting at least (clearing to the left or right) if you maintain a start index offset.